# GET dataevents using REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api

Is it not possible to GET dataevents by the REST API? I want to GET a dataevent and see what it's value is.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  The REST API isn't complete and it's super frustrating, I know.

I'd suggest using the [FuelSDK](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/) that combines both REST and SOAP API options.

You can definitely interact with [DataExtensionObjects](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/dataextensionobject/) using the SFMC SOAP API.

Reference: [Retrieving Data Extension Rows](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/data-extension-rows/data-extension-row-retrieve.html)