# How to get data from dataevents using REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I am trying to get rows from a dataevent object using REST API? I know this was previously not possible ([GET dataevents using REST API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/123715/get-dataevents-using-rest-api)) wondering if this has changed recently?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is still the same. Unofficially you can but officially you are not supposed to as this is not documented on SFMC Dev API docs. It's still a mystery why this is not available via REST routes though.